# ConTeXt: what is ~/texmf folder and what is its relation with /usr/share/texmf

Tags: context, linux, texmf

First of all, I am a complete noob in TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt/WhaTeVeR, so please be gentle.

OK so I installed ConTeXt (version 2013.84.svn30044-18.5) on my OpenSuSE 42.1 using the official repository, and tried running `context --version`. This gave me

```
...
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
...
```

After quite a lot of searching, I located the problem: ConTeXt apparently needs a file named `texmfcnf.lua` and for some reason it searches for it in

```
'home:texmf/web2c;/etc/texmf:/etc/texmf/web2c:/var/lib/texmf/web2c:$TEXMF/web2c'
```

while the only location where I could `find` this file is `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua`. So I linked the `/usr/share/texmf` folder to `~/texmf`, ran `mtxrun --generate`, and now everything works. However, I am quite sure that I did something stupid and not what was the good thing to do.

Is the search path for `texmfcnf.lua` correct? Maybe this is a bug in my OpenSuSE's package and the search path should include `/usr/share/texmf` instead?
If the paths list is correct, and the bug is in that there is no `texmf` folder at one of the listed paths, maybe I should have made a link from `/usr/share/texmf` not to `~/texmf`, but to e.g. `/etc/texmf`? Or maybe not a link but copy of the whole folder?
Or maybe the problem is with the environment and the bug is in that there is no TEXMF variable defined? If so, where should this var point to?

Comment: Could you say _how_ you installed ConTeXt?

Comment: @JosephWright from OpenSuSE repository. Version is 2013.84.svn30044-18.5 (`context --version` returns 2013.04.20 01:15).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it expects you to install the basics of TeX Live to support this. What does `luatex --version` give?

Comment: @JosephWright while installing ConTeXt the package manager pulled pretty much _everything_ related to TeXLive. `luatex --version` shows `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2015102513  (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (rev 4627)`

Comment: Just a piece of advice (also seeing the question about Cyrillic you asked): tex packages in linux distributions tend to be wildly out of date – as you can see, the OpenSUSE one installs a ConTeXt version that is more than 3 years old. Since you are interested in luatex, this will be a huge stumbling block: it has developed rapidly, and almost nobody runs a version this old. So do yourself a favor and install the minimal version from http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone. It can coexist with other TeX installations and make things much easier for you.

Comment: @Thomas will do, thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: Despite the older system, you should be able to learn about the search paths with `kpsewhich --var-value $1` (where `$1` is one of `TEXMFHOME`, `TEXMFLOCAL`, or `TEXMFDIST` ... or just plain `TEXMF`, while nothing that 'home' is search before 'local', which is searched before 'dist').